# How can I add responsive centered text to my HTML item in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know how I can add a responsive  centered text element to my `<a>` element? It shouldn't be affected by the overlay color. Please let me know if there is a clean alternative way of the extra overlay div. I am using Bootstrap 4.

http://jsfiddle.net/or74zoy0/1

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <a class="item" href="#">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-640-480-4.jpg" alt="" />
          <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image { position: relative;}
.image img { max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; }
.overlay { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right:0; bottom:0; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <a class="item" href="#">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-640-480-4.jpg" alt="" />
          <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <span class="title">Centered Text</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.image { position: relative;}
.image img { max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; }
.overlay { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right:0; bottom:0; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
.title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

## Or solving it with bootstrap classes:

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <a class="item" href="#">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-640-480-4.jpg" alt="" />
          <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="title d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            Centered Text
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.image { position: relative;}
.image img { max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; }
.overlay { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right:0; bottom:0; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
.title { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right:0; bottom:0;}
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your help!